# Wrong content-type(old header sent) being received by server side

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I updated afnetwork to 2.0 due to 64 bit. I made a mistake at first using AFHTTPRequestSerializer, but the server side accept Json only. The wried thing was it works fine for me even I used AFHTTPRequestSerializer, so I didn't notice this problem and released the error app to public. Then I keep receiving user complain and somehow I rebuild my app on my device, and local server can catch my wrong content-type(application/x-www.form-urlencoded). After I updated the AFHTTPRequestSerializer to AFJSONRequestSerializer, it doesn't fix the problem, but the user still keep sending wrong content-type to server even they updated the app. New user has no problem, only happen on old user.

Is this related to cache problem?

Server Log:

```
10:22:53 AM] Mark 1 contentType is: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,      method is: POST  headers are: Connection=keep-alive&Content-Length=1880739&Content-Type=application%2fx-www-form-urlencoded&Accept=*%2f*&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2c+deflate&Accept-Language=en%3bq%3d1&Cookie=ASP.NET_SessionId%3dbby5dlk5afmsnqnoqpprvqpw&Host


10:04:56 AM]        contentType is: application/json,                       method is: POST header is: Connection=keep-alive&Content-Length=40352  4&Content-Type=application%2fjson        &Accept=*%2f*&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2c+deflate&Accept-Language=en%3bq%3d1&Cookie=ASP.NET_SessionId%3dcw3gdkg3sff1f0j50z2rnism&Host
```

my code is

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:_url parameters:requestParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"operation success: %@\n %@", operation, responseObject);
    NSDictionary *decoded = [self processResponce:responseObject failureBlock:failureBlock];

                            if (!decoded) return;
                            BOOL containsError = [self checkErrorStatus:decoded failureBlock:failureBlock];
                            if (containsError) return;
                            successBlock(decoded[@"Data"]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        failureBlock(FailureTypeUnknown, [error localizedDescription]);
}];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
progressBlock(bytesWritten,totalBytesWritten,totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
```

Comment: I thinks it is header cache problem, the previous user keep sending the older header, anyone know how to update the cache?

Comment: after I did some research, I assume this error caused by default cache policy. Now I am adding policy to be NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData, hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

as per your response, please set your manager's content type as below

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
```

Comment: Does it matter with responseSerializer? Because the error happen on request header, rejected by Server side due to wrong content-type. Thanks for your help

Comment: yes Magrider, it's matter with responseSerializer. because the error was occur when responseSerializer not received acceptableContentTypes. you are always welcome Magrider.